# Modify a pointer if it's NULL in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to debug a program. It sets a pointer if this pointer is NULL. As you see, my code identifies that the pointer is NULL, and modifies it, however the result of the `printf` function is still the same, as if it did not modify

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    uint8_t x = 0;
    uint8_t* a = &x;
    uint8_t *b = NULL;
    printf("b: %p\n", (void*)&b);
    if (!b) {
        printf("modifying b\n");
        b = a;
    }
    printf("b: %p\n", (void*)&b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
b: 0x7ffe77813140                                                                                                                                                          
modifying b                                                                                                                                                                
b: 0x7ffe77813140
```

Comment: Why do you think the address of `b` would change when you change its value?

Comment: `&b` and `b` are different things.

Comment: As you might figure, first print doesn't show `0x0`.

Comment: "pointers are just like any other variables" is sometimes an oversimplification, though, here it is sufficient to understand the output you see

Comment: btw please dont tag c when the code is c++. Those are two different lanugages, with usually different answers.

Comment: b is pointer; (void *)&b, which you are printing, is a pointer to a pointer. You should do `printf("b: %p\n", (void*)b);` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however the result of the printf function is still the same, as if it did not modify
>
> ```
> printf("b: %p\n", (void*)&b);
> ```

This `printf` does not print the value of the (pointer) object. `&` is the addressof operator, so this prints the address where the object is stored. Changing the value of an object does not change where the object is stored. In fact, an object never changes position in memory.

You can print the value of a variable by passing it directly without using the addressof operator:

```
printf("b: %p\n", (void*)b);
```

Or more simply using iostream:

```
std::cout << "b: " << (void*)b << '\n';
```

P.S. The reason for needing conversion to `void*` is different in these cases. `printf` needs it because `%p` requires a `void*` specifically, and passing anything other violates this requirement.

All pointers can be passed to an iostream, but pointers to characters are special, and are printed as character string (like `%s` in `printf`) and `uint8_t` is typically an alias of `unsigned char`. As such in order to print the value of `uint8_t*`, we need to convert to another pointer type.

Comment: Ok, cleaned up my comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

you are using

```
 printf("b: %p\n", (void*)&b);
```

This will give the address of `b`. i.e. The memory location in which `b` is stored. This will be constant throughout the program even if the value of `b` is `NULL`.

You should use

```
 printf("b: %p\n", (void*)b);
```

Comment: i'd be careful with writing "you should". To me this always sounds as if the presented code is would be preferable also in a wider scope, but using `printf` vs `std::cout` is at best debatable